# Update Point using WFS Transaction with GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, wfs, wfs-t

I am trying to update a `Point` inside my PostGIS database that is connected with GeoServer.

I specify the new coordinates in the WFS-Transaction post message like this:

```
<gml:Point srsDimension="2" srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326">        
<gml:coordinates decimal="." cs="," ts=" ">0,0</gml:coordinates>
</gml:Point>
```

This works just fine.

However I am confused about the next step. The `Points` inside my PostGIS database are not in `EPSG:4326` but `EPSG:28992`. So I tried changing the `srsName` to `EPSG:28992` but this just makes GeoServer throw an exception.

How am I supposed to update Points using the EPSG:28992 projection?

If I update the points using `srsName="urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:4326"` GeoServer throws an PointOutsideEnvelopeException which is understandable.

Am I missing something here? Can I only update points using `EPSG:4326`?

Comment: are you putting urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:28992 or just EPSG:288992?

Comment: urn:x-ogc:def:crs:EPSG:28992

Comment: try just EPSG:28992

Answer (score 2):

I changed the WFS version from 1.0.0 to 1.1.0 and it works now.

I also set the native srs to EPSG:28992 in GeoServer.

Comment: that would make sense - 1.1 adds the concept of reprojection and without the native projection set GeoServer probably guesses wrong